# Как узнать: является ли значение буквенным

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно проверить:

```
letter = 'abc';  // => true
letter = 'ABC';  // => true
letter = '123';  // => false
letter = '_!$*'; // => false
```

И соответственно проверка выдаст `true` и выполнит код. Регистр, не важен. Числовые значения учитываться не будут.

P.S. Я попробовал управляющими последовательностью проверять, но либо неправильно проверял, либо не те значения.

Comment: "управляющими последовательностью" - это что?

Comment: @Igor https://codebra.ru/ru/lessons-javascript/types/6/1 - \s, \d, \n

Comment: Ваш вопрос не поняли. Приведите примеры данных и результатов проверки для них.

Comment: буквы каких алфавитов должны быть? Всех?

Comment: @ВадимЛешкевич можно и английского (латинский)

Comment: @Pon4iPay всё равно не понял. Можно и латинского или только латинского? Если будут кириллические символы, немецкие, арабские - это true?

Comment: @Вадим Лекшевич если можно, то конечно да. Но я прошу только латиницу

Comment: Зачем было ставить галочку напротив единственного неправильного ответа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Регулярное выражение `/^[a-zA-z]+$/` проверит строку на наличие исключительно строчных и прописных символов латинского алфавита.

```js
var pattern = /^[a-zA-z]+$/;

console.assert(pattern.test('abc'), {msg: 'abc'});
console.assert(pattern.test('ABC'), {msg: 'ABC'});
console.assert(!pattern.test('AB9'), {msg: 'AB9'});
console.assert(!pattern.test('123'), {msg: '123'});
console.assert(!pattern.test('ab$'), {msg: 'ab$'});
console.assert(!pattern.test(123), {msg: 'number: 123'});

console.log('all test passed');
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var foo = 'ASD'; // true
// var foo = 'asd'; // true
// var foo = '123'; // false
// var foo = '_$!%@'; // false

if (typeof(foo) === 'string' && foo.match(/^([а-яё][А-ЯЁ]+|[a-z][A-Z]+)$/i)) {
  console.log('true');
} else {
  console.log('false');
}
```

Comment: все символы пройдут проверку и числовые, и буквенные, и даже спец символы

Comment: @Pon4iPay, обновил.

Comment: можно ли проверить единый символ, а не строку?

Comment: Да. `/[a-zA-Z]/.test('a') // true`, `/[a-zA-Z]/.test('1') // false`

Answer (score 1):

Проверка на буквы латинского и русского алфавита, если на все алфавиты, то тут задолбаешься регулярку писать)

```js
const letters = 'AвВSqD'; // true

if (letters.match(/^[a-zа-яё]+$/i)) {
  console.log('true');
}
```

Comment: *то тут задолбаешься регулярку писать* - я бы не был столь категоричен. В средах JS, поддерживающих стандарт ECMAScript2018, достаточно написать `/^\p{L}+$/u`.